# XML Deserialization and string format

Tags: c#, .net, xml, string-formatting, xml-deserialization

I have an XML like this:

```
"<ArrayOfClsLog xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
<ClsLog>
<Subject>sth</Subject>
<Value>123456</Value>
<Comment>val</Comment>
</ClsLog>
</ArrayOfClsLog>"
```

and with this code I desterilize it:

```
var tmpSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<ClsLog>));
tmpResult = tmpSerializer.Deserialize(tmpReader) as ObservableCollection<ClsLog>;
```

here is my `ClsLog`:

```
 public class ClsLog
    {

        
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Value {get; set;}
        public string Comment { get; set; }
     

}
```

Everything is fine except:

**Big Problem**

I want the content of `value` which can be a number like `123456` converts into `123,456`

So I've changed Clslog to :

```
 public class ClsLog
    {

      
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Value {
            get
            {
return decimal.Parse(Value.ToString()).ToString("N2", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  
}
            set
            { }
        }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

But nothing changed, also I've tried to change tmpResult with LINQ:

```
tmpResult=tmpResult.ToList().ForEach(i => i.Value  =
 decimal.Parse( i.Value.ToString()).ToString("N2", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

So bad exception happened and turned out I can't change it manually.

**Question**

How I can fix it? (make `value` from 123456 to 123.456)

Comment: If value is a string the exact string value will be captured when deserialised, why do you think that it has a comma in it? What evidence is there to suggest there is a comma in the value that is read when deserialising?

Comment: Ah sorry, read this wrong, is the value actually a string? If not why are you deserialising as a string? If it's a numeric value, make the field numeric. If you want to format it with a comma, use the string formatting methods that already exist.

Comment: @charleh  I want the number which goes from value tag to tmpResult contains  comma.

Comment: Yes but is it a number or a string value? If a number, why are you deserialising to string?

Comment: @charleh yes value is a string I'm deserializing the whole of XML. I've tried string formatting but they won't work.

Comment: I'm a  deserialising  a string because I want it to have comma

Comment: There's a difference between formatting and data, if the value is a number, deserialise as a number as that's what type the value is. Format how you want it elsewhere, where are you displaying the data that you need it to have a comma? Does it appear on a web page, in a text box or on a report or something else?

Comment: @Charleh, I've tried to change ClsLog and type of value to `decimal` but deserilization's process stopped and tmpresult have not made so I kept type of value in ClsLog as a string.

Comment: But the value is numeric, so I can't see there being a problem unless value is not numeric, what error do you get?

Comment: @Charleh, I don't have any error I want the number which is is in value and now is successfully deserialized and I have successful access appears with comma like 123,456

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring this property wrong.

```cs
public string Value //why a string why not a decimal?
{
    get
    {
        // you have an infinite recursion here 
        return decimal.Parse(Value.ToString()).ToString("N2", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    set { }  // the setter is empty anyway so youcan't set it. 
}
```

Instead try this

```cs
private decimal _value;  // internal field
public decimal Value
{
    get
    {
        return _value;  // return internal field
    }
    set
    {
        _value = value / 1000;   // set the internal field to the value / 1000
    }
}
```

Comment: when I declare it as a decimal exception happens and it doesn't deserialize.

Comment: Works for me https://dotnetfiddle.net/FWxfOB